# Quickblox QBLGeoDataGetRequest: currentPosition is always "200.000000;200.000000"

Tags: quickblox

I'm trying to get all the check-ins near some point on the map:

```
QBLGeoDataGetRequest *getRequest = [QBLGeoDataGetRequest request];
getRequest.currentPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.0, 10.0);
getRequest.radius = 100;
[QBLocation geoDataWithRequest:getRequest delegate:self];
```

But strangely this code transforms to the following request:

```
GET http://api.quickblox.com/geodata/find.xml
headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.5.2";
    "Qb-Token" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
parameters:{
    "current_position" = "200.000000;200.000000";
    radius = 100;
}
```

"current_position" is always "200.000000;200.000000", whatever I change getRequest.currentPosition to.
But why? And how to fix this?

P.S. There's no code that could cause any side effects, I just authorize and perform the QBLGeoDataGetRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try updated QuickBlox iOS SDK 1.7 http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Download_iOS_SDK

This feature works OK in last version